# How to pass last visited url to passport.authenticate - node.js express app

Tags: node.js, express, session, authentication, passport.js

In my application's login route I'm using a passport.authenticate() method:

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", 
    {
        successRedirect: "/",
        failureRedirect: "/login"
    }), function(req, res){ });
```

But there is implemented fixed redirect url's only. I would like to pass last visited route address - url to this process, but in this implementation authenticate() method didn't take request and response parameters.

Comment: did you save the url you want to redirect anywhere?

Comment: No, I would like to do it in some kind of 'smart' way, maybe by using session or something. I don't have so many experience with web services.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current url using "req.url" and save into session just before you are redirecting the user to /login

```
req.session.recentUrl = req.url
res.send()
```

Now modify /login route to

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local",{
        successRedirect: req.session.recentUrl,
        failureRedirect: "/login"
}), function(req, res){ });
```

Note : Make sure to clear the req.session.recentUrl after handling appropriately.

**edit: req is not defined** 
you this middleware in you post route.

```
app.get('/protected', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, profile) {
    if (err) { return next(err) }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/signin') }
    res.redirect('/account');
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

This issue is already addressed,more info :https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/1

Comment: There is a problem with access to 'req' in passport.authenticate() - ```req is not defined```

Comment: yes..that's an issue..the docs were updated : more info @ https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/1